# Base docker image for windows service

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I have the app and also the windows worker (service). I need create the image for worker. But I dont understand what base image should I use? Maybe this one is right https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet with tag 5.0.17-windowsservercore-ltsc2019, 5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019.
I use .net 5. The docker container will be for Linux.

Comment: You start by saying it's for Windows and then you end by saying it's for Linux. Can you edit your post and clarify what OS you're targeting?

Comment: @HansKilian My current OS is windows. Image will be for Linux.

Comment: The you should use Linux images like `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`

Comment: Note that .NET 5 is EOL and all of the 5.0 Docker tags will no longer be maintained after June 14.