# Dockerfile for windows service

Tags: .net, dockerfile

I have some windows service. I need to create image for OS Linux. But I don't understand what will be my Dockerfile. Now I dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0

WORKDIR /src

COPY MyWindowsService/bin/Release/ MyWindowsService/Services/

RUN sc create serviceTest binPath=Path\MyWindowsService.exe

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell"]
CMD Start-Service \""serviceTest\"";
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but there is no way to run a Windows Service inside a container with a Linux OS.

Comment: Related [Base docker image for windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72392303/205233)

Comment: See [Dockerizing a Windows Service (.NET)](https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerizing-a-windows-service-net/18415)